# Renamed Web project, now finding ambiguous namespaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET web project, which was named "OldProject".  For whatever reasons, it was decided to rename the project and its namespaces to "NewProject".  Now when the site starts up, it complains about ambiguous controller names:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Admin'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> The request for 'Admin' has found the following matching controllers:
>
> OldProject.Controllers.AdminController
>
> NewProject.Controllers.AdminController

I have searched the entire solution, including the Web project's `csproj` file, and cannot find a single instance of the string "OldProject".

How to resolve this false ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename your project so that the file name of the assembly changes, it's possible for you to have two versions of your ASP.NET assembly, which will reproduce this error.

The solution is to go to your bin folder and delete the old dlls. (I tried "Rebuild Project", but that didn't delete 'em, so do make sure to check bin to ensure they're gone)